# How to make Jest spOn second call of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have nested Postgres queries. So when I test I want Jest.spyOn to resolve with different response

```
const query1 = 'SELECT NOW() as now'
const query2 = 'SELECT * from table1'

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pgClient
      .query(query1)
      .then(res => {
        pgClient
          .query(query2)
          .then(res => {
            resolve(res.rows[0])
          })
          .catch(e => reject(e.stack))
      })
      .catch(e => reject(e.stack))
});
```

So my test will look like:

```
  jest.spyOn(pgClient, 'query').mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ rows: [...] })
  );
```

So how do I resolve for query1 and query2 different response in same test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `mockImplementation` return different responses depending on what argument you pass to it:

```
jest.spyOn(pgClient, "query").mockImplementation(query => {
  if (query === query1) {
    return Promise.resolve({ rows: [1] });
  } else if (query === query2) {
    return Promise.resolve({ rows: [2] });
  }
  return Promise.resolve({ rows: [] });
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-hill-66qqb)

Comment: Thank you El Aoutar Hamza.. It works perfect